# How to time how long it takes to mine a block?

Tags: ethereumjs

I've recently created a private ethereum blockchain and would like to time, personally, how long it will take to mine a block in the private blockchain I have created. I'm using the command line/geth JSON-RPC interface, so if there's a way to time how long it takes to mine a block from within the JSON-RPC CLI interface and put it in a file that would be very helpful.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to _time_ the block generation time as opposed to calculate it? (As suggested above)

Answer (score 0):

with the commandline:

```
eth.getBlock(83).timestamp-eth.getBlock(82).timestamp
```

where 83 and 82 are block numbers

with RPC just use `eth_getBlockByNumber` function